# Solving for $Y$, using a utility function

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, utility

The question asks to solve for $Y$, below are the steps I tried to use:

$U = \ln X + 3 \ln Y \iff U = \ln X + \ln Y^3 \iff  \ln Y^3 = U - \ln X$

How can I move on from here if I need to isolate, why?

Answer (score 1):

You can express it using the exponential function
\begin{eqnarray}
U= \ln{X} + 3\ln{y}\\
\ln{y}=\frac{U-\ln{X}}{3}\\
y=X^{-\frac{1}{3}}\exp{\frac{U}{3}}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thank you Michael, Can you do the steps in more detail, why is it exp^U/3.

Comment: Exp(ln(y)) = y. After that you apply the rules for exponentials